# Find causing a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, find

I have a shared library for library interposition with an unordered_map.
The unordered_map is filled and consulted through the execution of an application (when intercepting specifics calls).

If I try to find an element in the constructor of the library, it generates a segmentation fault.

Here is the code for the constructor causing the segmentation fault:

```
void __attribute__((constructor)) init(void) { 
    void * address =  __builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0));
    printf ("Size: %i\n", stats._regions.size()); // works fine
    auto regionIt = stats._regions.find(address);
    printf ("Never reached\n");
}
```

Stats is declared in the header, like this:

```
class Stats {
  public
    std::unordered_map<void *, RegionInfo> _regions;
}
```

As said, if I do the find when intercepting specific calls (not in the constructor), it works fine.

Comment: Impossible to say, but could be SIOF.

Comment: How can I test if is SIOF? And fix it if that's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the code for the constructor causing the segmentation fault:

You didn't show how the `stats` global itself is declared, and without that your code is useless (see also [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

But this is almost certainly an instance of static initialization order fiasco.

> How can I test if is SIOF? And fix it if that's the case

The usual way to fix SIOF: instead of declaring `stats` as a global, make it a function-static and return a reference to it, which guarantees that it will be initialized before you access it:

```
Stats& get_stats()
{
  static Stats stats;
  return stats;
}
```

Your constructor will then look like this:

```
void __attribute__((constructor)) init(void) { 
  Stats& stats = get_stats();
  // rest as before
}
```

If this fixes the crash, you'll know that it was an instance of SIOF.